# How to add callbacks into an MDX file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I'm trying to create a storybook story within an MDX file that uses a callback. I can't figure out how to do this and the docs are very light so I'm wondering if anyone knows how to approach this?

```
<Meta title="Components/Droplines" component={Droplines} />

export const DroplinesTemplate = (args) => (
    <Chart
        onStoreCreated={(store) => {
            store.dispatch({
                type: "EVENT.ADD_DROPLINE",
                payload: {
                    isHorizontal: true,
                    color: "steelblue",
                    x1: 150,
                    x2: 0,
                    y1: 150,
                    y2: 150,
                }
            });

            store.dispatch({
                type: "EVENT.ADD_DROPLINE",
                payload: {
                    isVertical: true,
                    color: "steelblue",
                    x1: 150,
                    x2: 150,
                    y1: 150,
                    y2: 0,
                }
            });
        }}
    >
        <Droplines />
    </Chart>

);
```

Whenever I try to put anything inside the callback I get warnings during the runtime and the storybook story is no longer available:

> ./src/components/Droplines/Droplines.stories.mdxModule build failed (from ./node_modules/@mdx-js/loader/index.js):SyntaxError: /home/ian/src/chart-it/src/components/Droplines/Droplines.stories.mdx: Unexpected token (14:15)  12 |                     y2: 150,  13 |                 }> 14 |             });

Does anyone know what the correct approach is for adding in code to handle callbacks/events?

Comment: Hello Ian, have you tried extracting the `DroplinesTemplate` component into a separate file and just importing it into MDX? I'm not sure you can use "export" or other advanced  syntax there (I've used MDX, but never with storybook)

Comment: @Drago96 I haven't, thanks. I might give that a try :)